# CSS apply property to li which has specific class

Tags: html, css

I have a problem to apply css to the li element which has specific class. I want to change the background color of that li, but I couldnt find a way to do that. I am not sure about if this is changing 'parent' since I know css cant control parent.

CSS

```
.navi ul li { padding:20px; background-color: #00; }


.navi ul li + .current_location { background-color: #FFF; }

or

.navi ul li .current_location { background-color: #FFF; }

//will only change the background color of letters inside, no the li element.

current_location + ul li { background-color: #FFF; }

// will only apply to the children of the li which has class .current_location.



I want to change the li background color where it has class .current_location;
```

HTML

```
   <nav class="navi">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a>General Config</a>
              </li>
              <li class="current_location">
                <a>Menu</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a>User Level</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a>User</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a>Tag</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a>Log</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
```

Thank you very much for your advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.navi ul li + .current_location` should be `.navi ul li.current_location`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9EN3C/)

The `+` selector is used for selecting `next` element after the element.
Ex: `div+p` will select all `p` element which are coming after a `div` element. [example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_element_pluss)

Comment: Thank you very much for your example. It works. But how come in my code it will only apply to the letter background not to the li?? please advice

Comment: It might mean there are other interfering css styles, Can you inspect the `li` element and share styles

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space between **.current_location** & **LI**. Write like this:

```
.navi ul li.current_location { background-color: #FFF; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but it will only apply to the letter not the li, I stated that in my question

Comment: it's not clear to me. Please can you create an example for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

.navi ul li.current_location { background-color: #FFFFFF; }